# Blank login page in Laravel Project

Tags: php, html, laravel

Simple issue, the login page instead comes up as a white screen with a "404 not found" error. I will post the code for my index page that should have the working link to log in. All the things I'm using with this project are all up to date (Laravel itself, Phpstorm, composer etc.).

```
</html>`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100 h-screen antialiased leading-none font-sans">
<div class="flex flex-col">
    @if(Route::has('login'))
        <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 mt-4 mr-4 space-x-4 sm:mt-6 sm:mr-6 sm:space-x-6">
            @auth
                <a href="{{ url('/home') }}" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase">{{ __('Home') }}</a>
            @else
                <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                @if (Route::has('register'))
                    <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                @endif
            @endauth
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="flex flex-col justify-around h-full">
            <div>
                <h1 class="mb-6 text-gray-600 text-center font-light tracking-wider text-4xl sm:mb-8 sm:text-6xl">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </h1>
                <ul class="flex flex-col space-y-2 sm:flex-row sm:flex-wrap sm:space-x-8 sm:space-y-0">
                    <li>
                        <a href="login.blade.php" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="Login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="register.blade.php" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="Register">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="home.blade.php" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="Home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://nova.laravel.com" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="Nova">Nova</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://forge.laravel.com" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="Forge">Forge</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="Vapor">Vapor</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="GitHub">GitHub</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://tailwindcss.com" class="no-underline hover:underline text-sm font-normal text-teal-800 uppercase" title="Tailwind Css">Tailwind CSS</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the login page that should appear.

```
    <?php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <main class="sm:container sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:mt-10">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="w-full">
                <section class="flex flex-col break-words bg-white sm:border-1 sm:rounded-md sm:shadow-sm sm:shadow-lg">

                    <header class="font-semibold bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-5 px-6 sm:py-6 sm:px-8 sm:rounded-t-md">
                        {{ __('Login') }}
                    </header>

                    <form class="w-full px-6 space-y-6 sm:px-10 sm:space-y-8" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                            <label for="email" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 sm:mb-4">
                                {{ __('E-Mail Address') }}:
                            </label>

                            <input id="email" type="email"
                                   class="form-input w-full @error('email') border-red-500 @enderror" name="email"
                                   value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                            @error('email')
                            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic mt-4">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                            <label for="password" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 sm:mb-4">
                                {{ __('Password') }}:
                            </label>

                            <input id="password" type="password"
                                   class="form-input w-full @error('password') border-red-500 @enderror" name="password"
                                   required>

                            @error('password')
                            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic mt-4">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <label class="inline-flex items-center text-sm text-gray-700" for="remember">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" class="form-checkbox"
                                    {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                <span class="ml-2">{{ __('Remember Me') }}</span>
                            </label>

                            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                <a class="text-sm text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700 whitespace-no-wrap no-underline hover:underline ml-auto"
                                   href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="w-full select-none font-bold whitespace-no-wrap p-3 rounded-lg text-base leading-normal no-underline text-gray-100 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 sm:py-4">
                                {{ __('Login') }}
                            </button>

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <p class="w-full text-xs text-center text-gray-700 my-6 sm:text-sm sm:my-8">
                                    {{ __("Don't have an account? Register for free") }}
                                    <a class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700 no-underline hover:underline" href="{{ route('register') }}">
                                        {{ __('Register') }}
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
@endsection
```

Comment: Why is there `<?php` in your blade file?

Comment: That first HTML code is in there twice, is that on purpose?

Comment: `404 not found` error means, your blade is not rendering.  post your route along with controller

Answer (score 1):

I can not see @yield('content') in your master blade. Add it and  will work

Comment: Does it matter what line this goes on? Just been trying with our suggestion, while it accepts this line of code, it still gives me a 404 when I try go to the login page.

Comment: Please post route i.e web.php 404 error is not related to template.